# Dynamic URL change without page reload

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to change URL of a website without reloading page? (Without "#" or `Javascript.popState()` event ).

For example : if I click a button change URL from `/` to `/new_url` with no page reload.

If is it possible, I'd like to use pure JavaScript, and I need cross browser support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is: **No**

You will need to use the URL hash. They were created just to do that.

> In JavaScript, the fragment identifier of the current HTML or XHTML
>   page can be accessed in the "hash" property location.hash — note that
>   Javascript can be also used with other document types. With the rise
>   of AJAX, some websites use fragment identifiers to emulate the back
>   button behavior of browsers for page changes that **do not require a reload, or to emulate subpages**.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Still, I don't get it. What is your problem with hashes anyway?

Comment: Nice reading (+1 for that). But I still don't see a problem on the hash use **if** we use it wisely.

Comment: That limits it to only linking to actual content that appears on the page itself (and hiding that content only if JS is available). Using it to describe what Ajax content to load is a (too) common use case.

Comment: problem with hashes is that, it cant be fetch in backend, it can only be read by javascript only.. so on new page, i have to load cotent from javascript, rather then i can do it from backend.. facebook lint does not work eaither.. if you need to put description of the page. :/

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using [pushState](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushState), although cross browser support is limited (but you can [fall back to reloading the page](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider)).